# React: Sort function causing retroactive side effects my store?

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Tools:

Reactjs 0.14.0

Vanilla Flux(not sure if that affects the nature of this question.

---

I ran into a bug today that had me scratching my head for awhile. **In my store I was trying to access the first element in an array but it wasn't the expected element.**

I did print outs of the array as it entered the store and even after it emitted that the store was updated and the array looked as it should but if I accessed it eg `data[0]` it wasn't was the print out showed.

**Afterwards I finally found that a sort was being called AFTER the data was sent to the store.**

Like So:

```
ServerActionCreators.receiveData(data);
data.sort(mySortingFunction);
```

**My Question:**

**Why is the data in the store being retroactively updated? How do React developers ensure that these retroactive side effects don't affect the synchronous manipulation of their stores?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because both you and the store hold references to the **same array** and the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method mutates it.

It is possible to avoid this behaviour by staying well away from methods that directly mutate arrays (`push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, `reverse` and `sort`) **or** making a copy of the array before performing any of these actions.

```
var data = [ ... ];

// give the store a reference
MyStore.sendData(data);

// copy the reference before mutating it
var sorted = copy(data).sort(sortFn);

// continue to work with the copy
// ...
```

There are a number of ways to copy an object or a list, depending on which version of Javascript you are using.

```
// ES7
const copy = list => [...list]
// ES6
const copy = list => Object.assign([], list);
// ES5
function copy(list) {
  return list.map(function(item) {
    return item;
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an immutable [list](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) or [vector](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/#vector) to solve this problem.

```
// mori.js
var data = mori.vector( ... ),
    sorted = mori.sort(sortFn, data);

// immutable.js
var data = Immutable.list( ... ),
    sorted = data.sort(sortFn);
```

By definition these data structures won't be mutated when you call their methods.